# Fancybox 3 clicked "THIS" element ID Read problem from v2 to v3

Tags: fancybox-3

At V2 of fancybox, I could easily JS read an attribute ID of the clicked element for further use. It doesn't work with v3, I am wondering what's the problem, it was called at beforeShow

beforeShow: function() {

```
         var tagid = this.element.attr('id');
         alert(tagid);
```

}

Fancybox throws me an error as "undefined", meaning the click I have no idea what registers, but with v2 it was ok.

So basically passing any additional parameter through attributes that worked before, I can't read at beforeshow, or beforeload, or this is a different logic now at fancybox 3 so I have no idea...

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there is a reason why v3 is v3 and not v2, because these are ... well, different versions and you have to check docs on how to use new API. Therefore take a look at https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#events where you will find this snippet:

```
// Clicked element
console.info( slide.opts.$orig );
```

So, the ID of clicked element would be:

```
 slide.opts.$orig.attr('id')
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and while the first place I went was the documentation, clearly, afterShow is not the place to do this. I need to get the ID of the clicked element before the Show, so I can use that id to overlay something on the picture presented by fancybox. If I check the jquery object that comes back on the click, it contains everything fancybox does already (fn init etc) so it seems a bit trickier to get the attr I need..

Comment: Actually...it works with aftershow, probably I was too stuck with the logic of the v2 version. Thank you!

Comment: Last question, as you are the dev I know your time is super tight.

Previously, it was possible to edit the template for: "this.tpl.image='<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" /><div style="position:absolute;"id="image-hotmap-container"></div>',"

Is there a way to do it now as well? Basically I'd like to put a div as you see over the shown image.

Edit: Base tpl, thanks!